# python regex comma separated value csv of 3 characters

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a set of 3 lowercase letter csv's and I want to use the re.match function in python to extract them. I am using regex to obtain the results.
My csv is `' sdh  , ash,  vbn'` I want to capture all of them by skipping the white spaces and the commas. However, I don't get the correct output. I am getting this list as a result: (',vbn',)  . The expression is like this: `re.match('^[a-z]{3}((?:,?)[a-z]{3})*')`

Answer (score 0):

You might just match 3 characters surrounded by word boundaries:

```
csvText = ' sdh  , ash,  vbn'
matches = re.findall(r'\b\w{3}\b', csvText)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = ' sdh  , ash,  vbn'
m = re.match('(\w+),(\w+),(\w+)', inp.replace(" ", ""))
if m:
    print(m.groups())
```

Answer (score 0):

This regexp will match all characters but whitespaces and commas:

```
import re

line = ' sdh  , ash,  vbn'    
print(re.findall(r'[^\s,]+', line))
```

Prints:

```
['sdh', 'ash', 'vbn']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match), you might use:

[`\s*([a-z]{3})\s*,\s*([a-z]{3}),\s*([a-z]{3})\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/sBACIf/1)

That will match zero or more times a whitespace charcter `\s*`, capture in a group 3 lowercase characters `([a-z]{3})` followed by zero or more times a whitespace character `\s*` and a comma for the first 2 sets of 3 charactes. For the last set the comma is not matched at the end.

```
import re
match = re.match(r'\s*([a-z]{3})\s*,\s*([a-z]{3}),\s*([a-z]{3})\s*', ' sdh  , ash,  vbn')
if match:
    print(match.groups())
```

Result:

```
('sdh', 'ash', 'vbn')
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/IFI41677)

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I want the delimiter to either be one or more spaces, a comma  or a mix of several spaces and one comma. I want to refuse the input if it doesn't match the pattern i.e if there is an additional comma. Also, if there is only one value to the csv, I want it to detect it i.e. second and more values shall be optional. That was actually what I was trying to do.

Comment: More like this: sdh  , ash ,vbn,ajk 
and gives an error on this:  sdh,ash, ajk,        because of the comma

Comment: In that case you could consider using findall with [`\b([a-z]{3})\s*(?:,|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/oudUTD/1) [Demo with Python](http://rextester.com/QRVO68629)